# Как узнать какая горячая клавиша (хоткей) была нажата?

Tags: delphi, windows, hotkeys

```
type 
  TForm1 = class(TForm) 
    ..
  private 
    procedure OnHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey); message WM_HOTKEY; 
  end; 

...

procedure TForm1.OnHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey);
begin
  if .. then // <<-----
    Edit1.Text := '44'
  else if .. then // <<-----
    Edit1.Text := '55';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RegisterHotKey(Handle, Ord('U'), 0, Ord('U'));
  RegisterHotKey(Handle, Ord('P'), 0, Ord('P'));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  UnregisterHotKey(Handle, Ord('U'));
  UnregisterHotKey(Handle, Ord('P'));
end;
```

Что мне надо изменить, чтобы при нажатии на <kbd>U</kbd> писалось `44` а при нажатии на <kbd>P</kbd> писалось `55`?

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы назначаете хоткеям индексы (второй параметр в `RegisterHotKey`), вы можете сравнивать непосредственно с ними:

```
procedure TForm1.OnHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey); 
begin 
  if Msg.HotKey = Ord('U') then 
    Edit1.Text:='44';
  if Msg.HotKey = Ord('R') then 
    Edit1.Text:='55'; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Доброго дня! 
Можно обработать нажатия определенных клавиш на форме в событии OnKeyDown. Там 2 переменные обозначающие отправленные служебную (Shift.. etc) клавишу и простую.